# 404 after changing URL in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url

I wanted to make a website for my dad on his birthday. He already had one active through one.com with the URL www.virumfarveogtapet.dk.
I made one with wordpress on the URL test.virumfarveogtapet.dk and when I decided for it to be nice enough to go live I changed the URL with wordpress to the actual www.virumfarveogtapet.dk.

When i try to log into it www.virumfarveogtapet.dk/wp-admin it gives me this error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /wp-admin was not found on this server.

And if I try to access the website through www.virumfarveogtapet.dk it refers to my dads old homepage.

When I go into wordpress it still stands as test.virumfarveogtapet.dk but when I click it, it refers to my dads old homepage also.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have changed the URL of the WordPress installation to http://www.virumfarveogtapet.dk/.

You may be able to login and change the URL back to the "test" subdomain here: http://test.virumfarveogtapet.dk/wp-login.php

If not try updating the site URL with via FTP in wp-config.php or functions.php as per the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php

Comment: After adding the two lines, i can now access my site. But it looks really different! test.virumfarveogtapet.dk

Comment: What do you mean by "different"? Could you be more specific to what has changed?

Comment: I ended up going 2 days back in my database

Comment: Can't say that is possible. Those changes only affect a couple rows in the database int the wp_options table.